# How can I convert binary UUID to UUID in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm reading data from Hbase using spark and the UUID in Hbase is in binary format and I want to convert that binary type of UUID into regular UUID in scala. Anyone know how can it be done?

Comment: Can you confirm the full namespaces for the HBase UUID and regular Scala UUID (for example, are they both java.util.UUID)?

Comment: Whatever serializer was used to serialize the data to the HBase... use the corresponding deserializer.

Comment: if you used java.util.UUID while writing to HBase you should face no problem in de serializing it using the same package

Comment: @Woodz, They are using Phoenix mapper when they are saving it to Hbase. Can I get any code sample which can Do this on a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for resolving the question.

```
def touuid(a: Array[Byte]): String = 
{
  val bb   = ByteBuffer.wrap(a)
  val high = bb.getLong();
  val low  = bb.getLong();
  val uuid = new UUID(high, low);
  return uuid.toString()
}

val havid = udf((x: Array[Byte]) => touuid(x))
```